# Explain what this function does

Tags: c

Can anyone explain, at a level that a novice C programmer would understand, what this function does?

```
unsigned getunsigned(unsigned char *bufp, int len) {
    unsigned value = 0;
    int shift = 0;
    while (len--) {
        value |= *bufp++ << shift;
        shift += 8;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I guess the line that's giving me the most trouble to wrap my head around is:

```
value |= *bufp++ << shift;
```

Also, can anyone provide a way to re-write this so that it is more clear for an inexperienced C programmer to understand?

I found this code online while doing research for an assignment and I prefer not to use it unless I understand fully what it's doing and how it's doing it.

Comment: `*bufp++` should be cast to `unsigned` before the left-shift. Otherwise, it is promoted to `int` by default, and, when the shift is for the highest byte, the result may exceed what is representable in an `int`. Then the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is taking successive bytes from the buffer pointed to by `bufp`, and putting them into `value`.

The `value |= *bufp++ << shift;` is taking the value at `bufp` (i.e., the `char` at the address `bufp` is pointing at) and ORing it with 8 bits of `value`. Then it's incrementing `bufp` to point go the next byte in the buffer. After that, it adds 8 to `shift` -- that's what determined *which* 8 bits of `value` the new bytes gets ORed. I.e., `shift` starts as 0, so in the first iteration, the first byte of `bufp` replaces the bottom 8 bits of `value` (replaces, because they're starting out as 0). In the next iterator, the next byte of `bufp` gets shifted left 8 bytes, to replace the next 8 bits of `value`, and so on for `len` bytes.

Aside: if `len` is greater than `sizeof(unsigned)`, this is going to write past the end of `value`, causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
value |= *bufp++ << shift;
```

is equivalent to

```
value = value | (*bufp << shift);
bufp++;
```

Comment: @rekire. No, not at all. You should do a little reading on how [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) works.  The only time they would be equivalent, is if the bitwise intersection (AND) of the operands was zero. In other words, `0x10 | 0x04 == 0x10 + 0x04 == 0x14`.  But `0x10 | 0x10 != 0x10 + 0x10`

Comment: Actually, it is equivalent to `value = (uint8_t)(value | ((int)*bufp << shift)); bufp++;` because of integer promotions. In this particular case, I don't think the integer promotions will cause any bugs though.

Comment: @Lundin: When `*bufp` is promoted to an int and left-shifted, it may produce a value not representable in an int. Then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Only if the original uint8_t contained a negative value, but it cannot do that, it can only hold values from 0-255. So that's why this particular case will work (out of luck).

Comment: @Lundin: First, it is an `unsigned char`, not a `uint8_t`. Second, if the vale is, for example, 0x80, and is shifted 24 bits in a 32-bit `int`, the result would be 0x80000000. This is not representable in a 32-bit `int`, so the result is undefined per C 2011 6.5.7 4.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah good point, I didn't consider left shift overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
value |= *bufp++ << shift;
```

is equivalent to

```
value =  value | (*bufp << shift);
bufp++;
```

first value at bufp is shifted to the value in shift and the resultant is ORed `|` with `value` and then `bufp` is incremented.

At last value of shift is changed by `shift +=8` means `shift = shift + 8`

So it takes all the bytes in the `bufp` because while loop won't terminate until `len` becomes `0`.